# Using Apache Licensed font for mobile

Tags: mobile, apache-license, fonts

We are looking to incorporate an open source font which uses the Apache License v2 in our mobile application. I have a couple of questions on proper procedure/etiquette:

For a font, does creating an application that incorporates the font count as a derivative work (in other words, do we need to include the Apache license somewhere)? I always assumed that a "derivative work" for a font would mean making new fonts based on the original font, but a partner suggested that the license also applies to any application that incorporates the font.

Secondly, if we are required to display the license, how do we go about this on mobile where there are no accessible text files (e.g. NOTICE, README, LICENSE) included with the install? Do we put it in the license on the store? In a screen somewhere in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying someone else's work into yours makes yours a derivative work, even if you don't modify anything.

In the Android world, it's common to add acknowledgements and copyright notices to the Settings menu, as a menu item on the end.  Look at some of the apps from Google that come pre-installed for examples.